# Why is sorting the timestamp using order by or latest is only sorting by date and not by time?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel. I added this line to the controller

```
$remarks = Remarks::where('document_id', $document->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC)->get();
```

or

```
$remarks = Remarks::where('document_id', $document->id)->latest('created_at')->get();
```

And I use `foreach` to get each remarks.
These are the results for `$remark->$description`

> Nov. 10, 2019 - 8:29 am
> Oct. 10, 2019 - 2:49 pm
> Oct. 10, 2019 - 3:57 pm
> Sep. 13, 2020 - 2:06 pm
> Sep. 13, 2020 - 2:08 pm

It should be

> Sep. 13, 2020 - 2:08 pm
> Sep. 13, 2020 - 2:06 pm
> Nov. 10, 2019 - 8:29 am
> Oct. 10, 2019 - 3:57 pm
> Oct. 10, 2019 - 2:49 pm

Also, even when I am changing the `orderBy` to ASC or DESC it doesn't affect anything in the view, it always show this

> Nov. 10, 2019 - 8:29 am
> Oct. 10, 2019 - 2:49 pm
> Oct. 10, 2019 - 3:57 pm
> Sep. 13, 2020 - 2:06 pm
> Sep. 13, 2020 - 2:08 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that it appears you are storing *text* timestamps, and furthermore these timestamps are not in a format which would allow sorting by them to give any meaningful chronological order.  One workaround here is instead of sorting on this:

```
Nov. 10, 2019 - 8:29 am
```

sort on this as a date, using `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
STR_TO_DATE('Nov. 10, 2019 - 8:29 am', '%b. %d, %Y - %h:%i %p')
```

We can use `orderByRaw` in Laravel to do this:

```
$remarks = Remarks::where('document_id', $document->id)
    ->orderByRaw("STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%b. %d, %Y - %h:%i %p') DESC")
    ->get();
```

As some general advice, you might want to consider making your `created_at` column either `datetime` or a `timestamp` in MySQL.  If you do this, then sorting descending will work without having to resort to using `STR_TO_DATE`.